# OnClose is not working with Dialog or Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am using MUI v5.14.14 and for one of the dialog, the `onClose` function is not working even though click is able to call that function.

After using console.log, I can see that the State value is not changing which is responsible for the open and close of the dialog.

```
const [modalOpen, SetModalOpen] = useState(false);

const handleCommentChange = (value) => {
    setComment(value);
  };

  const handleCommentSubmit = () => {
    // Add your code
  };

  const handleCommentOpen = () => {
    setModalOpen(true);
  };

  const handleCommentClose = () => {
    setModalOpen(false);
    console.log(modalOpen);
  };

// In return section 
         <Button
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "flex-start",
              flexWrap: "wrap",
              cursor: "pointer",
              color: "#2C515C",
              backgroundColor: "transparent",
              textTransform: "none",
            }}
            onClick={handleCommentOpen}
            disableRipple={true}
          >
            <CommentOutlinedIcon
              sx={{ fontSize: "16px", margin: "15px", marginRight: "5px" }}
            />
            <span>Comment</span>
            <Dialog open={modalOpen} onClose={handleCommentClose}>
              <DialogTitle>Your Comment</DialogTitle>
              <DialogContent>
                <MdEditor
                  hideHeader
                  placeholder="Add your comment"
                  theme="light"
                  language="en-US"
                  preview="false"
                  scrollAuto="true"
                  noHighlight="true"
                  modelValue={comment}
                  onChange={(modelValue) => {
                    handleCommentChange(modelValue);
                  }}
                  toolbars={[
                    "bold",
                    "italic",
                    "-",
                    "title",
                    "sub",
                    "sup",
                    "quote",
                    "unorderedList",
                    "orderedList",
                    "task",
                    "-",
                    "codeRow",
                    "code",
                    "-",
                    "revoke",
                    "next",
                  ]}
                />
              </DialogContent>
              <DialogActions>
                <Box margin={{ sm: 3, xs: 2 }}>
                  <Stack spacing={1} direction="row" justifyContent="flex-end">
                    <Button
                      size="small"
                      color="error"
                      variant="outlined"
                      onClick={handleCommentClose}
                      sx={{
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        textTransform: "none",
                        ":hover": {
                          bgcolor: "error",
                          color: "error",
                          border: "error",
                        },
                      }}
                    >
                      Cancel
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      variant="contained"
                      color="success"
                      size="small"
                      onSubmit={handleCommentSubmit}
                      type="submit"
                      sx={{
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        textTransform: "none",
                        bgcolor: "#1e8e3e",
                        border: "#1e8e3e",
                        color: "white",
                        ":hover": {
                          bgcolor: "#1e8e3e",
                          color: "white",
                          border: "#1e8e3e",
                        },
                      }}
                    >
                      Save
                    </Button>
                  </Stack>
                </Box>
              </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
          </Button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: `console.log` after changing state will always show the old value

Comment: Thanks Konrad. But if I am using useEffect, its updating the state immediately and not allowing me to open the comment box.

Comment: Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can see the problem you're encountering.

Comment: Thanks Sam, but I changed the way I was planning to use the useState. I made it as a separate component and pass that as a props and things started working as expected.